# UIProgressView setProgress issue

Tags: swift, uiprogressview

[image]

I've encountered an issue using a `UIProgressView` where low values (1% - about 10%) look off. You can see with the example above that 97% looks accurate while 2% does not.

Here's the code for setting colors:

```
self.progressView.trackTintColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
self.progressView.tintColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(1.0)
```

But, if I comment out the trackTintColor or the tintColor, then the 2% looks correct. Why when using these together does it cause this issue? Just an Xcode bug? Has anyone resolved this before?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue in my project. For me it's fixed by using `progressTintColor` instead of `tintColor`.

```
progressView.progressTintColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(1.0)
progressView.trackTintColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to create color image 
SWIFT 3 Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!   

    @IBAction func lessButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let percentage  = 20
        let invertedValue = Float(100 - percentage) / 100
        progressView.setProgress(invertedValue, animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func moreButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let percentage  = 80
        let invertedValue = Float(100 - percentage) / 100
        progressView.setProgress(invertedValue, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //create gradient view the size of the progress view
        let gradientView = GradientView(frame: progressView.bounds)

        //convert gradient view to image , flip horizontally and assign as the track image
        progressView.trackImage = UIImage(view: gradientView).withHorizontallyFlippedOrientation()

        //invert the progress view
        progressView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: -1.0)

        progressView.progressTintColor = UIColor.black
        progressView.progress = 1

    }

}

extension UIImage{
    convenience init(view: UIView) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
        view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.init(cgImage: (image?.cgImage)!)

    }
}

@IBDesignable
class GradientView: UIView {

    private var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    private var vertical: Bool = false

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        // Drawing code

        //fill view with gradient layer
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds

        //style and insert layer if not already inserted
        if gradientLayer.superlayer == nil {

            gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            gradientLayer.endPoint = vertical ? CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1) : CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
            gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
            gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]

            self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
        }
    }

}
```